# SQL Server 2008 Stored Proc Performance where Column = NULL

Tags: sql-server

When I execute a certain stored procedure (which selects from a non-indexed view) with a non-null parameter, it's lightning fast at about 10ms.  When I execute it with a NULL parameter (resulting in a FKColumn = NULL query) it's much slower at about 1200ms.

I've executed it with the actual execution plan and it appears the most costly portion of the query is a clustered index scan with the predicate IS NULL on the fk column in question - 59%!  The index covering this column is (AFAIK) good.

So what can I do to improve the performance here?  Change the fk column to NOT NULL and fill the nulls with a default value?

```
SELECT  top 20 dbo.vwStreamItems.ItemId
            ,dbo.vwStreamItems.ItemType
            ,dbo.vwStreamItems.AuthorId
            ,dbo.vwStreamItems.AuthorPreviewImageURL
            ,dbo.vwStreamItems.AuthorThumbImageURL
            ,dbo.vwStreamItems.AuthorName
            ,dbo.vwStreamItems.AuthorLocation
            ,dbo.vwStreamItems.ItemText
            ,dbo.vwStreamItems.ItemLat
            ,dbo.vwStreamItems.ItemLng
            ,dbo.vwStreamItems.CommentCount
            ,dbo.vwStreamItems.PhotoCount
            ,dbo.vwStreamItems.VideoCount
            ,dbo.vwStreamItems.CreateDate
            ,dbo.vwStreamItems.Language
            ,dbo.vwStreamItems.ProfileIsFriendsOnly
            ,dbo.vwStreamItems.IsActive
            ,dbo.vwStreamItems.LocationIsFriendsOnly
            ,dbo.vwStreamItems.IsFriendsOnly
            ,dbo.vwStreamItems.IsDeleted
            ,dbo.vwStreamItems.StreamId
            ,dbo.vwStreamItems.StreamName
            ,dbo.vwStreamItems.StreamOwnerId
            ,dbo.vwStreamItems.StreamIsDeleted
            ,dbo.vwStreamItems.RecipientId
            ,dbo.vwStreamItems.RecipientName
            ,dbo.vwStreamItems.StreamIsPrivate
             ,dbo.GetUserIsFriend(@RequestingUserId, vwStreamItems.AuthorId) as IsFriend
             ,dbo.GetObjectIsBookmarked(@RequestingUserId, vwStreamItems.ItemId) as IsBookmarked
    from dbo.vwStreamItems WITH (NOLOCK)
    where 1 = 1
    and vwStreamItems.IsActive = 1
    and vwStreamItems.IsDeleted = 0
    and vwStreamItems.StreamIsDeleted = 0
    and (
            StreamId is NULL
            or
            ItemType = 'Stream'
        )


    order by CreateDate desc
```

Comment: What is the selectivity of `IS NULL`? Can you show the query?

Comment: What parameter is NULL? Do you have covering index on the view or  base tables? And for *all* columns in the SELECT clause?

Comment: Sorry, I worded the question a little poorly.  It's not that a parameter is null.  It's just the StreamId is NULL that's bogging it down.  Changing the query to StreamId = XXX is lightning fast

Answer (score 2):

When it's not null, do you have

```
and vwStreamItems.StreamIsDeleted = 0
and (
    StreamId = 'xxx'
    or
    ItemType = 'Stream'
    )
```

or

```
and vwStreamItems.StreamIsDeleted = 0
and (
    StreamId = 'xxx'
    )
```

You have an OR clause there which is most likely the problem, not the IS NULL as such.

The plans will show why: the OR forces a SCAN but it's manageable with StreamId = 'xxx'. When you use IS NULL, you lose selectivity.

I'd suggest changing your index make StreamId the right-most column.

However, a view is simply a macro that expands so the underlying query on the base tables could be complex and not easy to optimise...

Answer (score 0):

The biggest performance gain would be for you to try to loose GetUserIsFriend and GetObjectIsBookmarked functions and use JOIN to make the same functionality. Using functions or stored procedures inside a query is basically the same as using FOR loop - the items are called 1 by 1 to determine the value of a function. If you'd use joining tables instead, all of the items values would be determined together as a group in 1 pass.

Comment: That's what I was initially thinking, but the cost of these operations in 0%, compared to the IS NULL operation being 59%

Comment: @E-Madd - The cost of scalar UDF's isn't reported properly in the execution plan but I doubt this is actually your issue as you have `top 20` which should mitigate the impact of RBAR UDFs a bit and the  `StreamId = XXX` case doesn't seem to have a problem.